# Insert a class to a div and a line of html

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms

I have this **code**:

```
<div class="form-group label-floating">
<label class="control-label">Name <small>(required)</small></label>
<input name="name" type="text" class="form-control">

<label for="name" generated="true" class="error"></label>

</div>
```

Now I want to insert a **.css class** here:

```
<div class="form-group label-floating HERE NEW CLASS">
```

Now based on that class that can be *error/succes*, I want to write a line of **html** after input line:

```
<span class="material-icons form-control-feedback">clear</span>
```

I want to make this for every field in my form.

In case of error should be:

```
<div class="form-group label-floating **has-error**">
<label class="control-label">Name <small>(required)</small></label>
<input name="name" type="text" class="form-control">
**<span class="material-icons form-control-feedback">clear</span>**
<label for="name" generated="true" class="error"></label>
</div>
```

In case of succes :

```
<div class="form-group label-floating **has-succes**">
<label class="control-label">Name <small>(required)</small></label>
<input name="name" type="text" class="form-control">
**<span class="material-icons form-control-feedback">done</span>**
<label for="name" generated="true" class="error"></label>
</div>
```

I did this:

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        $(element).parent('div').addClass('has-error');
        //$('.form-group').append('<span class="material-icons form-control-feedback">clear</span>'); // add the clear ico

     },
     success: function(element) {
        $(element).parent('div').addClass('has-success');
        //$('.form-group').append('<span class="material-icons form-control-feedback">done</span>'); // add done ico

     },
```

It's works, but afther a invalid input is corected still shows error and if I try to put error/succes icons it's display multiple times.

Also if I try to show the error mesages, error/succes ico doesn't apear

Comment: When do you want to add a css class and when based on class the other line should be appended?

Comment: When the field contains errors I want to add the class has-error and display to <div class="form-group label-floating">,and afther input field add<span class="material-icons form-control-feedback">clear</span>. When the field is correct I want to add class has-succes and <span class="material-icons form-control-feedback">done</span> and should work for the entire form

Answer (score 0):

use `$('.form-group.label-floating').addClass("success");` to add class.
I suppose this is what you want and could get you going with what u wanna do

```js
$(function(){

  $('#btn').click(function(){
    $('.material-icons.form-control-feedback').remove();
    if($('input[type="text"]').val() != '') {
      $('.form-group.label-floating').addClass("has-success");
      $('input[type="text"]').after('<span class="material-icons form-control-feedback">done</span>');
    }
    else {
       $('.form-group.label-floating').addClass("has-success");
      $('input[type="text"]').after('<span class="material-icons form-control-feedback">clear</span>');
    }
    if($('input[type="email"]').val() != '') {
      $('.form-group.label-floating').addClass("has-success");
      $('input[type="email"]').after('<span class="material-icons form-control-feedback">done</span>');
    }
    else {
       $('.form-group.label-floating').addClass("has-success");
      $('input[type="email"]').after('<span class="material-icons form-control-feedback">clear</span>');
    }
  })
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group label-floating">
<label class="control-label">Name <small>(required)</small></label>
<input name="name" type="text" class="form-control">

<label for="name" generated="true" class="error"></label>

</div>
<div class="form-group label-floating">
<label class="control-label">Email <small>(required)</small></label>
<input name="email" type="email" class="form-control">

<label for="email" generated="true" class="error"></label>

</div>

<button id="btn" >submit</button>
```

Comment: How can I put everything in errorPlacement??? I have tryed but without a succes, I'm not very good with this. And input[type="text"] it's refer only to input elements of text type, how goes for other input types?

Comment: @sergiu best way is to assign input a class say `inputClass` and access input using `$('.inputClass')` or else `input[type="password"]` or `input[type="email"]` is the way. and i dont understand what do u mean by errorPlacement.

Comment: I have this now: errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            $(element).parent('div').addClass('has-error');
         } and I whant to change into what I described above, problem is I'm bad at this :(